# change the layout of a content type

Tags: theming, hooks, 7

I would like to change the layout of my content type.
I tried the syntax: page--content-type.tpl.php of Drupal 7.
but...I was not able to make the changes appear on the page.
When I write the file: page--node--numberNode.tpl.php work,
but when I write the file: page--content-type.tpl.php nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) there is no `page--content-type.tpl.php`, only `node--type.tpl.php`
If you have to use a `page-content-type.tpl.php` you must create a template suggestion. [This](http://bridgecitystudio.com/tutorials/create-page-template-anything-you-want) (d6) or [this](http://drupal.org/node/1089656#comment-5120152) (d7) might help you doing so.

Comment: I received the error is: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_get_types()". This feature has not been defined. Help me to run this hook please? (you see: Page template per content type)

Comment: Hm, it looks like the link above is for d6. Try the d7 equivalent: node_type_get_names() instead of node_get_types()

Comment: thank you! surely this is the error. But I can not fix it.
I tried with: $types = node_type_get_types ('names'); / $types = node_type_get_types();

Comment: I made a mistake on the link, it works very well. thank you!